# How to set environment variables for a shell command

Tags: command-line, sh

I often see this command in node.js programs: `NODE_ENV=test node app.js` which sets the NODE_ENV variable to test and works. I also read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable that this should work for any shell command, but running some tests on my own, here is what I see

```
$ HELLO="WORLD"
$ HELLO="MARS" echo "$HELLO"
  WORLD
$
```

I would expect this to print `MARS`. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56449

Comment: HELLO="MARS";echo "$HELLO"

Comment: HELLO="MARS" bash -c 'echo "$HELLO"'

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why `NODE_ENV=test node app.js` will work without the semicolon, but my example above requires a semicolon?

Comment: yes link of @BryanOakley explains it. when it is one line variable expansion occurs in one shot leading to 'HELLO="MARS" echo "WORLD" to be executed, when it is separated, HELLO="MARS" is firest evaluated like if i was on the above line...

Comment: Thanks had to read it a few times, before it got through to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `VAR=value command` means that the command will be invoked with the environment variable `VAR` set to `VALUE`, and this will apply only for the scope of that command.

However, when you are using the command line:

```
HELLO="MARS" echo "$HELLO"
```

The shell first interprets the `"$HELLO"` parameter, determines that it is `WORLD`, and then what it actually does is run:

```
HELLO="MARS" echo "WORLD"
```

So the echo may have the `HELLO` variable set, but it doesn't affect what it prints - it has already been interpreted before.

Doing

```
HELLO="MARS"; echo "$HELLO"
```

does something else entirely. First it sets `HELLO` to `MARS` in the current shell, and then it goes on to interpret the `echo` command. By this time `HELLO` contains `MARS`, not `WORLD`. But this is an entirely different effect - the variable `HELLO` stays with the value `MARS`, which is not the case in the command without the `;`.

Your problem is that `echo` is just a poor choice for a demonstartion of this. You can do other demonstrations to prove that `HELLO` is changed properly:

```
HELLO="MARS" eval 'echo $HELLO'
```

In this case, the shell will not interpret the `$HELLO` because it is within a string in single quotes. It will first put `MARS` in `HELLO`, and then call the `eval 'echo $HELLO'` with that variable set. The `eval` command with then run `echo $HELLO`, and you'll get the output you were expecting.

This syntax is best used for things that don't use the given variable as part of the command line, but rather use it internally.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct, but here a refinement :

There are 2 cases in fact when defining a list of variable separated by spaces in bash whether it ends or not with a command.

```
VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2 ... VARn=valuen command arg1 arg2 ... argn
```

and

```
VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2 ... VARn=valuen
```

**don't export VAR1 ... VARn the same way.**

In first case VAR1 ... VARn will be set only for command and will then not be exported to current shell.

In second case VAR1 ... VARn will alter current shell.

then ( remark that ';' is very same of using a new line )

```
HELLO=WORLD
HELLO=MARS echo "i don't export HELLO."
echo "HELLO=$HELLO"
```

will display

```
i don't export HELLO.
HELLO=WORLD
```

and

```
HELLO=WORLD
HELLO=MARS ; echo "i did export HELLO."
echo "HELLO=$HELLO"
```

will display

```
i did export HELLO.
HELLO=MARS
```